# OnAppearing event firing twice .with tabbed page

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am facing issue being a beginner for Xamarin forms and MVVM . I have tabbedpage and 2 pages are under      tag . Here is code.

Issue is local:ActiveOrderViewPage page OnAppearing() event is firing twice when tabbedPage is loading and execute twice code under OnAppearing() event .

Please help me to find this why this is happening ?

Here Is code  Tabbed Page
 tabbedpage.xaml

```
<TabbedPage
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        Title="Orders">
<TabbedPage.Children>  
      <local:ActiveOrderViewPage />  
      <local:SavedOrderViewPage />
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

tabbedpage.xaml.cs

```
  public partial class OrderTabViewPage : TabbedPage
{
    public OrderViewModel ViewModel { get { return BindingContext as OrderViewModel; } }
    public OrderTabViewPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     this.BindingContext = ViewModelLocator.OrderVModel;

    }
    public OrderTabViewPage(params object[] arg) : this()
    {
        if (arg != null)
        {
            ViewModel.AccountID = Convert.ToInt32(arg[0]);
        }
    }
```

Here is active order .cs

```
 public partial class ActiveOrderViewPage : ContentPage
{
    public OrderViewModel ViewModel { get { return BindingContext as OrderViewModel; } }
    public ActiveOrderViewPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      this.BindingContext = ViewModelLocator.OrderVModel;       
    }

    //public OrderViewPage() : this()
    //{
    //    ViewModel.AccountID = accuntId;
    //}
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        if (ViewModelLocator.OrderVModel.ActiveOrderItems == null || ViewModelLocator.OrderVModel.ActiveOrderItems.List.Count == 0)
        {
            ViewModelLocator.OrderVModel.ActiveOrderCommand.Execute(null);
        }


    }
```

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: could you please add what code you have tried ..because without that not able to configure your problem???

Comment: I have added code for both pages . Please have a look

Comment: having the same "issue"... did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Same here latest release.

Comment: Same here. And OnDisappearing is firing too when enter to the page

Comment: BTW, It seems to be related to this issue https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/348

Answer (score 2):

Having had this problem for a long long time, before realising, I know how frustrating this is. The event `OnAppearing()` fires twice because of the way that the tabbed page renders all of the individual pages. It initially renders the page, then in your case will render the other page, which causes the `OnDisappearing()` to fire. The first page then gets focus, causing the `OnAppearing()` to fire again.

If you only want the code to fire once, after adding the child pages, set the `currentpage` property to null, which should stop the `OnAppearing()` from firing again

Answer (score 0):

In my case OnAppearing called twice while i had in app.xaml the follow code:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

after i change the code to:

```
MainPage =new MainPage();
```

The OnAppearing is no more calling twice.